# Using jQuery to make a div fadein on mouseover of a link

Tags: jquery, mouseover

what I'm trying to do should be simple but it's complicated by the way the html is structured which I can't change. I basically need what stackoverflow has in the header when mouseover of your account happens. A little menu fades in and out again when the mouse leaves.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="top-links">
    <a id="my_link">Link</a>
    <div id="my_mouseover">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 $jQ('#my_link').mouseenter(function(){
  $jQ('#my_mouseover').fadeIn(200);
  $jQ('#my_mouseover').mouseleave(function(){
      $jQ('#my_mouseover').fadeOut();
  });
  $jQ('#my_link').mouseleave(function(){
      $jQ('#customer_mouseover').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

My problem is that the div fades back in and out when i move my mouse between the `<a>` and `<div>`. Is there some way to say:

```
$jQ('#my_mouseover').mouseleave(function(){
      //there's no such thing as mouseIsOver
  if(!$jQ('#my_link').mouseIsOver()){
    $jQ('#customer_mouseover').fadeOut();
  }    
});
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I'm not able of finding what I need on google.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` on the `top-links` div:

```
$('#top-links').mouseenter(function(){
  $('#my_mouseover').fadeIn(200);
});
$('#top-links').mouseleave(function(){
  $('#my_mouseover').fadeOut(200);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KJE7x/

Comment: That seems to work but if i add more links how would the disappear when moving to the next link? it seems im stuck at the same problem again. see http://jsfiddle.net/KJE7x/ again

Comment: If you use a class instead of an id you could achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/KJE7x/3/

Answer (score 0):

add the mouseenter and leave event to you parent container.. this will get the mouseover and mouseleave event for its shild element (`<a>` and `<div>`) too

```
$('#top-links').hover(function(){
  $('#my_mouseover').fadeIn(200);
},function(){
  $('#my_mouseover').fadeOut(200);
});
```

**NOTE: you can use [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) instead of creating two sepearte function for each event**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#top-links').on({
    mouseenter : function() {
        $('#my_mouseover').fadeIn(200);
    },
    mouseleave : function(){
        $('#my_mouseover').fadeOut(200);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems when adding additional links with the approach Pete shared with me, eventually this is what I did:

```
  $('#top-links').mouseenter(function(){
 $('#my_link').mouseenter(function(){
     //fade everything else out
     $('#my_mouseover2').fadeOut();
     $('#my_mouseover').fadeIn(200);
 });
 $('#my_link2').mouseenter(function(){
     $('#my_mouseover').fadeOut();
     $('#my_mouseover2').fadeIn(200);
 });
});
 $('#top-links').mouseleave(function(){

$('#my_mouseover').fadeOut(200);
$('#my_mouseover2').fadeOut(200);
});
```